# How can I redirect outputs from a Python process into a Rust process?

Tags: python, rust, ipc, file-descriptor, pipelining

I am trying to spawn a Rust process from a Python program and redirect Python's standard output into its standard input. I have used the following function:

```py
process = subprocess.Popen(["./target/debug/mypro"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

and tried to write to the subprocess using:

```py
process.stdin.write(str.encode(json.dumps(dictionnaire[str(index)]))) #Write bytes of Json representation of previous track
```

I am not getting any errors but standard input in Rust doesn't seem to take any input and standard output isn't printing anything at all.

Here's the version of the Rust code I am currently running:

```
extern crate rustc_serialize;
use rustc_serialize::json::Json;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io;
use std::env;
use std::str;

fn main(){
    let mut buffer = String::new();
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    //stdin.lock();
    stdin.read_line(&mut buffer).unwrap();
    println!{"{}", buffer};
    println!{"ok"};      

}
```

Comment: Someone may come up with a more direct answer to your question, but meanwhile let me suggest [ØMQ](http://zeromq.org/) for all your interprocess communication needs. It comes with bindings for both, [Python](https://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq) and [Rust](https://github.com/erickt/rust-zmq).

Comment: Sounds good. I've moved your question to the title of the post, which is where it belongs here on Stack Overflow. Next, I encourage you to [edit] your question to include the important pieces of information: What the program *does* and what you *expect* it to do.

Comment: *I haven't been able to find any way of opening a pipe using a file descriptor.* — except your code **shows that you did**: `pipe_in = unsafe { Stdio::from_raw_fd(fd) };  let mut my_pipe = Pipe::new();  my_pipe.reader = pipe_in;`.

Comment: @Shepmaster this does not work at all (I am very new to Rust)

Comment: Does this help? https://rustbyexample.com/std_misc/process/pipe.html

Comment: "this does not work at all" - then post errors or whatever problem you encountered? don't make others replicate the attempts that you already did.

Comment: @the8472 There is no runtime error. It just doesn't print out inputs from the other program. That's why I came here for help. Sorry if anything is unclear it's the first time I post here.

Comment: This is not the correct way to use `fork`. You're supposed to `fork` and then `exec` which replaces the child process. Instead, you're calling `subprocess.run` which does its own `fork`+`exec` and starts an external process. Your file descriptors won't be valid in that process.

Comment: Is Popen better ? @interjay

Comment: It's the same. `run` is a wrapper around `Popen`+`wait`. There's no point in forking if you're going to use that.

Comment: @MichaelKohl no it actually doesnt since it's spawning a subprocess from Rust .. I want somethoing like in C when u get a handle on a pipe using a file descriptor.

Comment: "but standard input in Rust doesn't seem to take any input " - how have you determined that?

Comment: @the8472 I printed out the inputs with the line "pintln!("{}", buffer)" which prints out inputs from the keyboard when i run the Rust process alone   .. but when I use the python program to launch it .. no inputs are printed out. they are supposed to come from the python process with the line "process.stdin.write(str.encode(json.dumps(dictionnaire[str(index)]))) ".

Comment: have you checked whether popen redirects stdout? have you tried printing before the read_line, which might block? does the process start and hang or not get started at all? you need to break down the problem into parts and *debug* step by step to figure out where it fails instead of just saying that it either works or doesn't.

Comment: @the8472 Im sorry I didn't get too much in the details of what I did. So yes I had printed before and after the read_line and it was printing so stdout is not redirected. it is indeed blocking on read_line.

Comment: @the8472 so thank you very much sir I found the solution ! "process.stdin.write" does not add a "\n" at the end of the data i am trying to send so read line never gets to the end of the line !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`process.stdin.write(str.encode(json.dumps(dictionnaire[str(index)]))` does not add a newline character by default, so on the Rust side I was never getting to the end of the line which was making the process block on `read_line`.

Adding it manually made everything work smoothly.

```
process.stdin.write(str.encode(json.dumps(dictionnaire[str(index)])+ "\n") )
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be a problem on the Python side

> ```py
> subprocess.run(["cargo run -- " + str(r)], shell=True)
> ```

This assumes that you have a numeric file descriptor that remains open across `fork` and `exec`. Spawning processes may close file descriptors either because they're marked as `CLOEXEC` or due to explicit cleanup code before `exec`.

Before attempting to pass a numeric file descriptor as a string argument, you should make sure that they will remain valid in the new process.

A better approach is to use some process spawning API that allows you to explicitly map the file descriptors in the new process to open handles or an API that spawns a process with stdin/out tied to pipes.

Comment: That is actually what I was trying to do .. opening handles on fd in new process. The problem is I can't find any API that does that in Rust. Then I tried your second approach. Please read the answer that I just posted below. thank you

Comment: the point is that there is no fd to open in the child process if it gets closed on the python side when spawning a child process.